# How can I add (custom) modules to Appearance -> Menus?

Tags: menus

Does anyone know how I can add (custom) modules to Appearance -> Menus? (Or has a link with explanation on how to do this) so that when people change their menu in the backend they can choose what to add to their menu (Pages - Post - Links - Categories - Tags - [custom module])

I ask this question because I want to build a one-page theme. I want to be able to add `<section>`s to the templates to separate the different 'pages'.
The (rough) idea I have, is create a function which 'scans' trough the templates, isolates the section ID's of these sections, and add them as a menu module to the backend. That way people would be able to add a menu item to one of these sections to their menus.

Comment: Why don’t you just register a post type for the sections with `show_in_nav_menus = TRUE`?

Answer (score 3):

When you register a custom post type, set the argument `show_in_nav_menus` to `TRUE`, and WordPress will create the box for you automatically. This works for custom taxonomies too.

Example, requires PHP 5.4 or newer.

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', function() {

    $post_type = 'foo';

    add_action( 'registered_post_type', function( $registered ) use ( $post_type ) {

        if ( $registered !== $post_type )
            return;

        register_taxonomy(
            'bar',
            $post_type,
            [
                'label'             => 'Bars',
                'public'            => TRUE,
                'show_in_nav_menus' => TRUE
            ]
        );
    });

    register_post_type(
        $post_type,
        [
            'label'             => 'Foo',
            'public'            => TRUE,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => TRUE
        ]
    );
});
```

Adding a custom box for anything else is more difficult. Well, **adding** it is easy, it is just a metabox with the parameter `$screen` set to `nav-menus`:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', function() {

    add_meta_box(
        'test',
        'Custom Box',
        function() {
            print 'Insert content here.';
        },
        'nav-menus',
        'side',
        'low'
    );
});
```

The difficult part are the following actions: creating the proper HTML for the list items, saving those items with AJAX requests and rendering them in a nav menu on front-end. Inspect the built-in boxes for the details. Repeating and explaining that would require a novel.

The out put of both code examples should look like this:

[image]

You can see the boxes for the post type **Foo**, the taxonomy **Bars** and the **Custom Box**. **Form** is one of my own post types on that installation, **Location** on of my taxonomies, and **Languages** a custom box for all available languages in a multilingual network built with Multilingual Press.